# How did Doctor Strange & Team do this?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In Avengers: Endgame, we see Doctor Strange and other sorcerers

> open multiple portals at multiple locations across the universe to bring all the help they can get to fight against Thanos' army.

When last seen, Black Panther, Falcon, Wanda, etc. were in Wakanda, Wasp was in San Fransisco, Ravagers were on their Ship/Planet somewhere in the universe.

So, my first question is, how were they able to open inter-planet portals? Has it happened before?

and the second, how did Doctor Strange and fellow sorcerers know where to open the portals and look for help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> how were they able to open inter-planet portals? Has it happened before?

In Doctor Strange (2016), Mordo clearly states that the ring is used to travel throughout the multiverse.

> Mastery of the sling ring is essential to the mystic arts. They allow us to travel throughout the multiverse.

So, yes it is possible.

> how did they know where to open the portal and look for the help?

## Most probably Doctor Strange knew the locations.

Doctor Strange had seen most of the scenarios of the war against Thanos -- around 14 million -- including the one that was shown in  *Avengers: Infinity War.*

So, he would be having some idea about locations of the battles when they got wiped out in *Avengers: Infinity War* as he had seen this scenario. After coming back from dust, Dr Strange would have felt that he came back from a deep sleep but will be having perfect memory of what was going on before he became dust.

He just needed to open the portals at those probable locations. And he would have led the sorcerers to those locations.

EDIT:

Based on Frank's comment:

Strange seems to come directly from the planet they got dusted on, so one can speculate that he would have stuck his head through some portal, told Wang and co. where to go.  It would require him to transfer knowledge of the places.
We can see that from the conversation between Strange and Wang which implies that he sent him to collect the rest.

Strange would have brought the guys from his planet (where he got dusted)  to Avengers Headquarters (where the battle is) and would have had his mages do the other portals.

Comment: A small nagging issue: If I remember right, Strange seems to come directly from the planet they got dusted on, so I'd wager he just stuck his head through some portal, told Wang and co. where to go and then brought the guys from his planet to Wakanda and had his mages do the other portals. Would require him to somehow transfer knowledge of the places, but most are quite easy to describe and it took them long enough to go looking around a bit to find everyone. While he might have come back for them, the conversation with Wang implies that he sent him to collect the rest.

Comment: @FrankHopkins  Valid points . Your comment certainly makes the thread better. Thank You!

Comment: *...then brought the guys from his planet to Wakanda and had his ...* I guess to Avengers Headquarters where battle was going on. Right?

Comment: ah, yes, right, had the first battle ground from IW in mind^^

Comment: Earth probably isn't the only planet to have sorcerers either. If the Ravagers were hanging somewhere cool, like Knowhere, there might have been someone around who knew how to get them to Earth

Comment: Do we know if a Sorcerer can open more than one portal? With Strange being the greatest of the Sorcerers, I wouldn't be surprised if he could open dozens of portals to many places all on his own.

Answer (score 2):

> how did they know where to open the portal and look for the help?

### **Strange said there was only one way to win**

Strange, in knowing this, would know everyone's locations, **IF** the Avengers managed to achieve the single future that would lead them to overcoming Thanos and succeeding.

If they didn't succeed, then everyone would not be where they should be. So it doesn't matter that Strange doesn't know where they are now, because they have already lost anyways.

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't need time stone to open the portal. as explained in Dr. Strange movie anyone can open a portal to anywhere the can imagine (I don't know how he got the Imagin what it looked like on that side of the war) also he got Wang to get some more people to open the portal and fight the war against Thanos.